# How to get data from a google spreadsheet?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want to make an android app where google spreadsheet will be my server.I am able to post data to the server(google spreadsheet) via google form but unable to get data from that spreadsheet.
My code is

public class ContactActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
public static final MediaType FORM_DATA_TYPE
        = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    public static final String URL="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/" +
        "XXXXXXXXX/formResponse";
    public static final String NAME="entry.XXXXXXXX";
public static final String PHONE="entry.XXXXXXXX7";
public static final String EMAIL="entry.XXXXXXXX";

private  Context context;
private EditText name;
private EditText ph;
private EditText email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
    context =this;

    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    ph = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString()) ||
                    TextUtils.isEmpty(ph.getText().toString()) ||
                    TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"All fields are mandatory.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if(!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email.getText().toString()).matches())
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Please enter a valid email.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            PostDataTask postDataTask = new PostDataTask();

            postDataTask.execute(URL,name.getText().toString(),ph.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

private class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... contactData) {
        Boolean result = true;
        String url = contactData[0];
        String n = contactData[1];
        String p = contactData[2];
        String e = contactData[3];
        String postBody="";

        try {

            postBody = NAME+"=" + URLEncoder.encode(n,"UTF-8") +
                    "&" + PHONE + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p,"UTF-8") +
                    "&" + EMAIL + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(e,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            result=false;
        }

        try{

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(FORM_DATA_TYPE, postBody);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        }catch (IOException exception){
            result=false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
                    Toast.makeText(context,result?"Message successfully sent!":"There was some error in sending message. Please try again after some time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you using the Google Drive SDK / API, or not? What code do you have?

Comment: this might help you - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android

Comment: i posted my code @cricket_007

Comment: i see the code does not use the drive api at all. go read the api docs for drive.

Comment: In addition to the reference above, you may check on this tutorial about [*Using Google Spreadsheets as Data Source in Your Android App*](https://github.com/telerik/Android-samples/tree/master/Blogs/Json-Reader). Basically, you'd access a Google Spreadsheet through a URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID]`. But if you want to get the same spreadsheet as a JSON response, you'll have to use its key to construct a URL like `https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=[ID]`.

Comment: @abielita, thank u for replying.I have gone through the sent link.But i dont want to get spreadsheet data through JSON response.Actually i want direct cell read , write and edit functionality.I also have gone through Spreadsheet API but unable to do this.